# Is it possible to have two sources of audio output to different speakers in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, audio

I have a Bluetooth speaker that I’d like to stream my Spotify music to while at the same time having my YouTube video from Chrome output sound to my monitor speaker. I’m using a DP cable. Is this possible to do in Windows 10?

Comment: There's an experimental feature in Spotify that allows you to decide which audio device it should use. See the description at https://community.spotify.com/t5/Live-Ideas/Allow-user-to-select-default-sound-device/idi-p/5351 on how to enable it.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I found two applications that allows you to do this.

[CheVolume](http://www.chevolume.com/) (Paid) - 7 day trial version available

[image: CheVolume Screenshot]

[Audio Router](https://github.com/audiorouterdev/audio-router) (Free) - open source alternative to CheVolume

[image: Audio Router GIF]

> Note: If not working you need to enable stereo mix in sound properties. Refer this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zvezLmCDBI) or this [GIF](https://media.giphy.com/media/3o7529LeCFFO1Htk8o/giphy.gif).

**Update after spring 2018**

With windows 10 spring update 2018, Microsoft is offering a similar solution. You can check the below GIF or this youtube [video](https://youtu.be/XbkHvQOHpdg?t=132).

[image: Windows 10 Sound Settings]

**Update December 2018**

EarTrumpet - Quick, simple control of all your audio devices from the taskbar. Get it [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/eartrumpet/9nblggh516xp).

[image: EarTrumpet - Move Apps Between Playback Devices]

*Supported operating systems*

- Windows 10 1803 (April 2018 Update)
- Windows 10 1809 (October 2018
  Update)

Comment: As far as UX goes, the free one looks better

Comment: I've used audio router to acheive this and it works well. I would live if it had the ability to persist, so audio from one app allways gets routed to the output device specified. Perha ps it does this, but I overlooked it.

Comment: Thank you. That link to the video about how to control sound sources in Windows 10 was helpful (https://youtu.be/XbkHvQOHpdg?t=132) because I was having trouble using VoiceMeeter Potato.

Comment: Of these (Windows 10 itself, CheVolume, Audio Router, and EarTrumpet), only EarTrumpet remembers and re-applies the setting if you close and re-open the routed program!! I tested them all August 2020.

Answer (score 5):

Though Codelt already answered the question, it should be known that the terrific Pulse Audio has builds available for Windows:

- [PulseAudio on Windows](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Ports/Windows/Support/)
- [Setting up PulseAudio 1.0 beta for Windows](https://parseq.co.uk/wordpress/archives/setting-up-pulseaudio-1-0-beta-for-windows)

Pulse Audio has been providing this feature on Linux desktops for about four or five years, therefore it is stable and reliable. Additionally, it is very scriptable so the user can have it automatically route based on conditions after some configuration. So far as I know neither of the mentioned Windows-only software are scriptable.

Answer (score 3):

You can now do this in later builds of Windows 10.
I don't know on which build it started.
Go to Settings --> Sound.
At the bottom, there's Other sound options --> 
[App volume and device preferences.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQgU3.png)

Comment: Can you find (or create) a new version of that image that’s clearer?  Like maybe black on white?

Comment: I see this in both Windows 1809 and 1903 (didn't try 1909).  It lets you pick the default output and input devices, and the default output/input for each application.

Answer (score -1):

1. Right click on sound icon near clock.
2. Select Open Sound Configuration.
3. Scroll down until Device preferences and ...
4. Change configuration.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jslKM.jpg

Comment: Can you be a bit clearer on how to change the configuration?